# @Output to parent does not update other children

Tags: angular

I have 3 components (note the [selected]="selectedTemplate==.... )

when the components are created the selected @Input makes it selected or not, and so active a particular css class

parent template :

```
<my-template-select [selected]="selectedTemplate==0" (onSelected)="onSelectedTemplate($event)" value="0"></my-template-select> 
<my-template-select [selected]="selectedTemplate==1" (onSelected)="onSelectedTemplate($event)" value="1" ></my-template-select> 
<my-template-select [selected]="selectedTemplate==2" (onSelected)="onSelectedTemplate($event)" value="2"></my-template-select>
```

when I click on one component it executes the select function

component template :

```
<div [ngClass]="selectedClass" (click)="select()" ></div>
```

which call back the parent with an @Output event

component controller :

```
select()
{
    this.selectedClass["templateSelectActiveDiv"]=true;
    this.onSelected.emit(+this.value);
}
```

But as the parent receives the value ...

```
onSelectedTemplate(templateID:number)
{
    this.selectedTemplate=templateID;
}
```

IT DOES NOT UPDATE the other children that should be deselected

what am I missing ?

thanks

Comment: `this.selectedClass["templateSelectActiveDiv"]=true;` indicates that selectedClass is some kind of array of booleans. In your template, you are doing `[ngClass]="selectedClass"`, meaning you are trying to use that array as the value for the `ngClass` directive. That is not how you should use `ngClass`. See docs: 

https://aio-staging.firebaseapp.com/api/common/NgClass

Comment: check the 3rd example from the link you provided, I use an associative array, so it should work, (and it does for that part)

Comment: the issue is about [selected]="selectedTemplate==..." not beeing refreshed

Comment: anyone ?????????